# How can I display the full path of file in KIVY?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy and I'm using FileChooserIconView to display the files. I am trying to display the current path of the file, however, it cannot show the full path of a file. It is possible to show the full path?

I have tried to set a root path, it can show the full path of a file. However, it will not show a “..” directory to go up to the root path. I want to show the ".." directory too.

This is my kivy code:

```
48 <Browse>:
49     title: 'Select the ouput directory'
50     size_hint: .8, .8 #the presentage size of the original window
51     auto_dismiss: False
52     FileChooserIconView:
53         path: '.'
54         id: fc2
55         filters: [root.is_dir]
57         BoxLayout:
58             size_hint_y: .1
59             orientation: 'horizontal'
60             GridLayout:
61                 size_hint_y: None
62                 height: 150
63                 rows: 2
64                 orientation: 'vertical'
65                 spacing:1.5
66                 BoxLayout:
67                     Label:
69                         text: "Path of directory: " + fc2.path
70                 BoxLayout:
71                     Button:
72                         text: 'Back'
73                         on_release: root.dismiss() #close the popup 
74                     Button:
75                         text: "Choose"
76                         on_release: 
77                             root.dismiss()
```

When I run this code and click the button "Browse", it will popup and show as follow:
Path of directory: .
and if I click "../", it can show the full path.

But I want to show the full path of the directory when I click the button "Browse".

Comment: Are you asking how to display the full path for every icon in the `FileChooserIconView` display? That can get messy when paths get long.

Comment: @JohnAnderson No, I am just asking how to show the full path of the directory. When I click into a folder, I want to know where am I. However, when the screen popup on the first time, it can just show "Path: ."  not "Path: /home/user/test" 
it makes people confused where they are.

Comment: Your posted code looks odd to me, especially lines 56 and 57. Doesn't that give you an error? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson It doesn't get any error. It can run in my program.

Comment: Can't do any more without a [mcve].